# How to remove rounded ends on line shp segments so they transition into each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line

I have a long line shapefile with segments representing different sample transects. The ends of the segments are currently rounded. As a result, some segments cover parts of other segments. Is there a way to remove the rounded ends? I would like them to just transition into each other.

[image: The ends of the lines are currently rounded and don't well represent the plots.]

Comment: Is this a *symbolization* issue on a POLYLINE shapefile, or actual multiple overlapping POLYGONs?

Comment: It is a polyline.

Comment: Edit the symbology of the layer to display lines with "butt" ends rather than rounded ends.